# Transpose a matrix in racket (list of lists

Tags: list, matrix, scheme, racket, transpose

I got a list of lists in racket and have to transpose them.

```
(: transpose ((list-of(list-of %a)) -> (list-of (list-of %a))))

(check-expect (transpose (list (list 1 2 3)
                               (list 4 5 6)))
              (list (list 1 4)
                    (list 2 5)
                    (list 3 6)))

(define transpose
  (lambda (xs)
    (cond
      ((empty? xs)empty)
      ((pair? xs)(make-pair  (make-pair (first(first xs))  (make-pair (first(first(rest xs)))empty)) (transpose (rest(rest xs))))))))
```

That's my code at the moment.
I think the problem is in the recursive call (correct me if I'm wrong please).

The actual outcome is `(list (list 1 4))`. The rest seems kinda ignored.

It would really help me, if somebody knows the problem, or has a tip.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest definition of `transpose` is:

```
(define (transpose xss)
  (apply map list xss))
```

Why does it work?

```
  (apply map list '((a b) (d e))
= (apply map List '((a b) (d e))    ; use List rather than list
= (map List '(a b) '(d e))
= (list (List 'a 'd) (List 'b e))
= '((a d) (b e))
```

Here `List` is spelled with capital letters only to show which `list` was given by the user and which was produced by `map`.

Here is a less "clever" solution. It uses that the first column of
a matrix becomes the first row in the transposed matrix.

```
(define transpose
  (lambda (xss)
    (cond
      [(empty? xss)         empty]
      [(empty? (first xss)) empty]
      [else                 (define first-column   (map first xss))
                            (define other-columns  (map rest  xss))
                            (cons first-column
                                  (transpose other-columns))])))
```

Comment: The equivalent in Python is `apply(zip, [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])`. I know you didn't ask about Python, but I'm offering this as general knowledge. Python has lots of lispy bits bodged together in 'junkyard-wars' style. It's also MUCH easier to share with friends than is any real lisp.

Comment: Servus to all my Informatik 1 students in winter 20/21.  

Please note that we have added the code above to our plagiarism checker.  Don't copy foreign code — try to get a grip on the problem on your own.  Thanks!

Greetings,
—TG

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (transpose xss)
  (apply map list xss))
```

If you are, like me, new to Scheme, you'll wonder how the `apply map list` trick works.
It all boils down to understanding `apply` and `map`.

First, `apply` does its job. It takes a function, some fixed arguments and a *list of arguments*.
It calls the function with the fixed arguments followed by the flattenned list arguments.
So:

```
(apply map list '((1 2) (3 4)))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- list of arguments
           ^^^^ ---------------- a fixed argument
       ^^^ --------------------- function
```

evaluates to:

```
(map list '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

Note how the list of lists is turned into two lists.

Now `map` accepts an N-argument function and N lists of equal length. Then it returns a list, where each element is an application of the function.
For example

```
(map + '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

evaluates to:

```
(list (+ 1 3) (+ 2 4))
```

In the transpose trick the function is simply `list`, so:

```
(map list '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

evaluates to:

```
(list (list 1 3) (list 2 4))
```

where the first `list` constructs a list because `map` always returns a list and the other two are invocations of the passed `list` function.

Answer (score 1):

`for/list` can be used sequentially to create a list of lists with transposed items:

```
(define (transpose_ lol)                    ; lol is list of lists
  (for/list ((i (length (list-ref lol 0)))) ; loop for length of first inner list
    (for/list ((il lol))                    ; for each inner list (il)
      (list-ref il i))))                    ; get its item
```

Testing:

```
(transpose_ (list (list 1 2 3)
                  (list 4 5 6)))
```

Output:

```
'((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (tr ls)
  (if (empty? (car ls)) empty
 (if (null? ls) empty
     (cons (map car ls) (tr (map cdr ls))))))
```

Comment: You can put your code in a code block by indenting 4 spaces.  Please also add an explanation of your answer, not just a block of code.

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by adding an explanation to your code-only answer.

Comment: question is from 2015