# Scheme add columns in a matrix

Tags: matrix, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function that takes a matrix (represented as a list of lists) and adds the elements down the columns and returns a vector (represented as a list):

Example:

```
    (define sample
      '((2 6 0 4)
        (7 5 1 4)
        (6 0 2 2)))
```

should return `'(15 11 3 10)`.

I was trying to use the `(list-ref)` function twice to obtain the first element of each column with no luck. I am trying something like:

```
(map (lambda (matrix) ((list-ref (list-ref matrix 0) 0)) (+ matrix))
```

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Transpose a matrix in racket (list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30775032/1281433).  Summing the columns just uses **+** instead of **list**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple if we forget about the indexes and think about higher-order procedures, try this:

```
(define sample
  '((2 6 0 4)
    (7 5 1 4)
    (6 0 2 2)))

(apply map + sample)
=> '(15 11 3 10)
```

Explanation: `map` can take multiple lists as arguments. If we `apply` it to `sample` (which is a list of lists) and pass `+` as the procedure to do the mapping, it'll take one element from each list in turn and add them, producing a list with the results - effectively, adding all the columns in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Was able to reuse this to my needs.