# Transpose a matrix in DrRacket without using apply?

Tags: matrix, scheme, racket, transpose

I am having trouble with transposing a matrix. I can transpose, but with three helper functions, which is not really efficient. I found some answers using `apply`. But are there any other ways to transpose without using it?

```
(check-expect (transpose (list (list 1 2 3)
                               (list 4 5 6)))
              (list (list 1 4)
                    (list 2 5)
                    (list 3 6)))
```

`lambda`, `local`, `map`, `foldl` and `foldr` and other built-in functions in student language are fine.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775032/transpose-a-matrix-in-racket-list-of-lists?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. Thanks =)